# Unable to detect wifi p2p group owner by legacy devices

Tags: linux-device-driver, fedora, wifi-direct, wifi

I am trying to create a wifi direct p2p Group owner using wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli. Once the group is create with p2p_group_add, how can we connect legacy wifi devices to the GO? I see the GO in Android mobile search, however I am not able to detect/find GO in legacy laptop with just wifi support. May I know if any configurations need to be done for supporting legacy devices like security type etc. Please suggest.

Comment: what OS is there in legacy laptop ? and how you are searching for AP/GO through wpa_cli or through GUI ?

Comment: Thank you. I am having fedora 19 where my p2p GO is running. Legacy device is running on Windows7. In windows laptop, i am trying to refresh my wlan. Also i tried manually adding the group ssid and passphrase which was generated as result of p2p_group_add in GO. Please let me know how can i move forward.

Answer (score 0):

An autonomous GO should be detected by any legacy wifi device - no special configuration is necessary. The GO should be beaconing and responding to any probe requests, both of which allow a legacy wifi system to detect it (it will just ignore the special P2P IE). 
I just tried the same scenario and both my Android phone and my Windows 7 laptop could see the GO running on my Linux laptop.
As your Android phone can see the GO then it is obviously responding to probe requests, so the fact your Windows machine cannot see it is likely to be an issue with the specific netcard used (either in your wpa_supplicant machine, or your Windows machine).
Some further debugging may be necessary to find the root cause, for example using wireshark, and if possible either upgrading the wifi netcard driver on your Windows machine, or swapping it out with a different vendor.